# Приближение содержимого WebView?

Tags: android, webview

Как реализовать приближение сожержимого WebView с помощью двойного касания, и обратного уменьшения с помощью тех же действий? Возможно за эти манипуляции отвечает какое-либо свойство?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вроде же по умолчанию данная фича доступна. Если нет, то это должно включить:

```
WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Comment: По умолчанию не работало, а вот код этот помог

Answer (score 2):

На некоторых сайтах может не зумиться, т.к. могут прописать, к примеру, такое:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

чем как бы говорят браузеру(WebView), что сайт подогнан под ширину Вашего устройства, минимум и максимум совпадают и вообще, нельзя зумить страницу.